# How can I process images with OpenCV in parallel using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, python-multiprocessing

I have a set of images in a folder that I want to preprocess using some OpenCV functions. The function

```
detectAndaligncrop
```

takes an image path preprocesses it using OpenCV and returns the utput image.
I am able to do it using:

```
for image_path in files_list:
   cropped_image, _=detectAndaligncrop(im)
   cv2.imwrite("ouput_folder/{}".format(os.path.basename(image_path)),cropped_im*255.)
```

However this is not working:

```
jobs=[]
for im_no, im in enumerate(files_list):
    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=saveIm,args=[im])
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```

where saveIm is:

```
im,lm=detectAndaligncrop(im_path)
        fname="output_path/cropped2/{}".format(os.path.basename(im_path))
        cv2.imwrite(fname,im)
```

I have verified that it calls the detectAndaligncrop function, but does not process image starting from the line where

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

is called inside detectAndaligncrop, because "before cvtColor" is called for every image, while "after cvtColor" is not:

```
def detectAndaligncrop(impath):
    image=cv2.imread(impath)
    image_float=np.float32(image)/255.0
    print ("before cvtcolor")
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print ("after cvtcolor")
    return gray, 1
```

Also,I tried:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as execr:
    res=execr.map(saveIm,files_list)
```

This works but no faster than simply running a for loop. Is it because of GIL?

Comment: Huh? We can't see the line you mention.

Comment: Made some changes

Comment: You should add the code for your `detectAlignandcrop()` function. Or, even better would be to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: added the code for the function detectAndaligncrop

Comment: What's the point of `image_float` please? And how can *"before cvtColor()"* be called without *"after cvtColor()"*?

Comment: the function actually other things also, I put a reduced version here to debug. This also doesn't work. "before cvtcolor" is printed for every image, while "after cvtcolor" does not get printed, and the cell in the notebook is shown to still be executing.

Comment: @Charlie you can use joblib library for this purpose. I have a snippet if you are interested.

Comment: Yes, please share it

Comment: @Amogh Hi did you give this a try? do let me know how efficient it is.

Comment: Not yet, I'll let you know this week. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I was in need of a multiprocessing approach to pre-process images before feeding them to neural networks. I came across this page called [Embarrassingly parallel for loops](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) where mathematical tasks were being run for elements in an array/list in parallel. I wanted to know if this could be extended to images (after all images are nothing but arrays, big 3D arrays!)

I decided to perform the [add weighted](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) operation from OpenCV to a collection of images. Using this operation you can apply different weights to two images and add them. It is used for blending images as you can [see here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_image_arithmetics/py_image_arithmetics.html#image-blending)

I performed this function **with** and **without** joblib for a set of images on my desktop and compared their performances. In the end I have mentioned the number of images and the collective size of these images used.

**Code:**

```
import os
import time

#--- Importing the required library ---
from joblib import delayed

#--- Choosing all available image formats of images from my desktop ---
path = r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop'
img_formats = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg']

#--- Defining the addWeighted function from OpenCV ---
def weight(im):
    addweighted = cv2.addWeighted(im, 0.7, cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (15, 15), 0), 0.3, 0)
    return addweighted


#--- Using joblib library-----
start_time = time.time()

new_dir = os.path.join(path, 'add_Weighted_4_joblib')
if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
    os.makedirs(new_dir)

def joblib_loop():
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if any(c in f for c in img_formats):
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, f))
            r = delayed(weight)(img)
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(new_dir, f + '_add_weighted_.jpg'), r)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print('Using Joblib : ', elapsed_time)

#--- Without joblib ---
start_time = time.time()

#--- Check whether directory exists if not make one
new_dir = os.path.join(path, 'add_Weighted_4')
if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
    os.makedirs(new_dir)

for f in os.listdir(path):
    if any(c in f for c in img_formats):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, f))
        r = weight(img)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(new_dir, f + '_add_weighted_.jpg'), r)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print('Without Joblib : ', elapsed_time)
```

Here is the result I got:

```
('Using Joblib : ', 0.09400010108947754)
('Without Joblib : ', 15.386000156402588)
```

As you can see using `joblib` speeds up operations like crazy!!

Now let me show you how many images are present on my desktop and what is the total size of them:

```
overall_size = 0
count = 0
#for f in os.listdir(path):
for  f in os.listdir(path):
    if any(c in f for c in img_formats):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, f))
        overall_size+= img.size
        count+= 1

print('Collective Size of all {} images in the predefined path is {} MB'.format(count, overall_size/10**6))
```

and the result:

```
Collective size of all 14 images in the predefined path is 58 MB
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to actually call joblib_loop()? I looks to me like you timed mkdir and def without actually computing anything.

Answer (score -2):

After a few experiments found the error:
Basically, the error is in the method to convert the read image into a grayscale one.
If I use :

```
gray = cv2.imread(impath,0)
```

instead of

```
image = cv2.imread(impath)
image_float = np.float32(image)/255.0
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

the code works fine,

Perhaps there is some problem in using cv2.cvtColor in MultiProcessing. Someone can shed light on the reasons. Is it about picklability?

Comment: Do other opencv functions work for you in multiprocessing?

Comment: This is not an answer. @Amogh has just identified that at cv2.cvtColor its not working.

Comment: cvtColor relies on numpy which handles parallelism on the backend.  When numpy heavy functions are run in parallel, the number of threads available to numpy is reduced, and hence it is slower.  If you're only doing numpy operations, it's very likely doing them in parallel will show you any benefit as the total number of threads won't be any different.

Comment: For example, 4x numpy operations on a 4 core machine run serial will run 4 threads on each numpy operation 4 times.  The same scenario in parallel will likely run 1 thread on each numpy operation in 4 parallel threads.  Depending on how you execute the operation, you could end up with an oversubscription to CPU resources and actually run 4 threads numpy operations in 4 parallel threads, resulting in 16 threads which end up fighting for CPU time and force swapping penalties which will be worse than either of the other 2 scenarios potentially.