# How to speed up data augmentation of images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on data augmentation using opencv2 in python. The dataset i am using consists of around 4000 96x96 single channel images.

I am applying a series of affine transformations of translating and scaling using 
`cv2.warpAffine`. However i have noticed that as the code iterates through the dataset, the process gets slower and slower. Code of the rotating transformation below - i call it on each image.

```
def augment_rotation(depth):
augment_rotate = []
rows,cols = depth.shape
for i in range(-180,181):
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(((cols-1)/2.0,(rows-1)/2.0),i,1)
    augment_rotate.append(cv2.warpAffine(depth,M,(cols,rows)))
return augment_rotate
```

This is not confined to my computer as i tried it on other computers and had the same issue. Any idea how to resolve this or make it faster so i dont have to wait hours for the augmentation to execute?

Comment: Are you storing the augmented images to your local hard drive?

Comment: Yes, the augmented images are pickled after the images are augmented

Answer (score 1):

I came across the `joblib` library built-in python. It is designed for this purpose. According to [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) `joblib` helps execute loops in parallel using the `multiprocessing` library in the backend.

The docs illustrate a numerical example for executing simple math operations for a list of numbers in parallel. I was able to extend this functionality to processing images. As a sample demo I opted to perform a weighted sum of all images on my desktop **with** and **without** `joblib`.

It turns out that for 14 images of collective size of 58Mb I got the following:

```
('Using Joblib : ', 0.09400010108947754)
('Without Joblib : ', 15.386000156402588)
```

[Here is the write-up for the answer I wrote recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935330/how-can-i-process-images-with-opencv-in-parallel-using-multiprocessing/51336402#51336402). I am sure you can use it for augmentation as well!!

Try it out and let me know how it works!